# After long sleep, screen goes blank if mousing over certain things

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, cursor, blank-screen

I have an HP Laptop 15-dy1751ms. If it sleeps for a while, (I don't know exactly how long) the screen will go blank if the cursor is hovering on different parts of the screen. (not caused by clicking) I noticed that it's usually if it's over an 'interactive' part of the screen, such as the password box on the lock screen. Restarting the computer temporarily fixes the issue, win+ctrl+shift+b does not.

EDIT: I updated my BIOS, now device manager gives me this for Firmware:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

Indicates a revision number encountered or specified is not one known by the service. 
It may be a more recent revision than the service is aware of.
```

Comment: Update the BIOS (UEFI), video, and Power Drivers, set the Power Plan to default, restart and test.

Comment: After the updates I suggest, mouse over the screen as you did and see if the problem continues.

Comment: sorry if i wasnt clear. it doesnt happen all the time. it is occasionally triggered by long sleep, don't know why

Comment: Well, update the drivers, use the computer and see.  It is not possible to otherwise say how to test a random occurrence.

Comment: It happened again: after shutting down for lack of battery, it gave me this issue after I turned it on

Comment: Run the HP hardware test app to see if there is a hardware problem.

Comment: all tests passed

Answer (score 0):

### Disable hibernation

Go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings` and select "Change advanced power settings" under Sleep>Hibernate after, change "On Battery" to 0

I don't know why hibernation was causing this problem, comment if you do.